# Searching public posts on facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm developing a Java business application and I need to search public posts on Facebook that contain specific keywords. I tried using the RestFB library but I quickly realised that making a public search for posts is not supported any more by the Facebook Graph API.

So, my question is the following: is there another way to search for Facebook posts?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other way. Public Post Search has been removed a long time ago and there is no alternative. There is only this one, but you can't apply: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed